# Storing function in DLL files

Tags: c#, function, dll

I would like to store C# functions in DLL files and later call that function with parameters. So far i've been able to store the function in a DLL file with the following code:

```
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
var parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.OutputAssembly = "Sum.dll";
icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
```

The function in the DLL file (value of variable code above is):

```
public class Function : IFunc
{
    public string ID
    {
        get { return ""Sum""; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return ""Sum""; }
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get { return ""Return the sum of the values specified in args""; }
    }

    public ResultSet Execute(params string[] args)
    {
        var sum = 0;
        foreach(var arg in args)
        {
            var rslt = 0;
            if(int.TryParse(arg, out rslt))
            {
                sum += rslt;
            }
        }

        ResultSet rtn = new ResultSet();
        rtn.Result = sum.ToString();
        rtn.Type = ""int"";

        return rtn;
    }
}
```

I've used Assembly.LoadFile to load the DLL and used reflection to fetch the class containing the function. I also have 2 identical interface, one in my project and one in the DLL file:

```
public interface IFunc
{
    string ID { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    string Execute(params string[] args);
}
```

To be able to call the function i use:

```
public static IFunc CreateSumFunction()
{
    var dll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"...\Sum.dll");
    var func = dll.GetType("Function"); // Class containing the function
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(func);

    return (IFunc)instance; // <--- CRASH
}
```

Part of the exception:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
>   Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'GenericCoder.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

Is there a way to resolve this, or maybe a complete new way of doing it?

Comment: Why are you using reflection when you can just create a simple class library and then reference the outputted DLL from your other projects?  Are you developing with Visual Studio?

Comment: no i cant, the DLL are created at runtime and used at runtime, not at project design

Comment: Are you trying to implement Addin functionality?

Comment: yes, sort of...

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus specify your *actual* problem, not what you did to solve it. You have a XAML page. What is it? You want to bind something to it dynamically. In a MVVM application you don't need to generate code at runtime btw, you can just change the content of a control and the view will be updated.

Comment: Also please update the title and text to reflect the actual question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -- I see your comment under the answer, and I'm confused...no one has downvoted the question...

Comment: its an application where programmers creates addin codes and stores it in dll files, then lower-authorisation users use these addins to perform some work...

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus -- In the future, you should include *all relevant information* in your question ahead of time.  The information you've given us here in the comments is pretty important, and will prevent people from voting your question down and closing it before giving it a chance.

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus .NET already has *two* addin mechanisms. Why create another one? Besides, you just need to load a type based on its interface and let XAML binding do its magic. Why use code generation at all???

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos addin functionality at runtime?

Comment: Addin is at runtime by definition. There's `System.Addin`, there's MEF and you probably don't need either if you have an IoC that can load assemblies from disk (all do)

Answer (score 0):

Add your library to references of your project. Then you're able to use the functions without the need of reflections.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T DOWNVOTE THIS QUESTION just because the OP used a bad title

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Nobody downvoted this question. Only this answer because it was not clear what the focus of the question was.

Comment: I meant this answer. I rushed to add a warning before more people punished the innocent. It has two downvotes and my upvote. This answer *does* answer the question as worded. The OP though wants something completely different, something that becomes apparent in the comments